# LINQ to ENTITIES DISTINCT return duplicates when LINQ TO SQL works as expected

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have been using LINQ to SQL for the last year and have had no problems. I decided that I wanted to experiment with the EntityFramework on a project where the requirement was to just return some raw data from several Views in a customer's database. I created the Entities model, included the Views, but when I wrote a query to return the distinct rows for a particular value duplicates were returned.

The only column with the EntityKey set to true was PWSID, but that column contains lots of duplicates. The following was my query:

```
int[] pwsIds = (from attribs in db.VW_DOR_ParcelAttribs_All
                select attribs.PWSID).Distinct().ToArray();
```

I created a LINQ to SQL data model and used the same query and everything works as expected. I didn't make any changes to either data model.

I did try to set that value of the EntityKey property to false but then I got a compiler error. I don't have control over the customer's table. There really is not a unique key.

For this application LINQ to SQL is acceptable and works great, but I am trying to better understand what I did wrong when I need to use the Entity Framework in the future. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntityKey should be set on properties or combinations of properties that are guaranteed to be unique in that table. I'm guessing EF is optimizing the `.Distinct()` away, because it assumes the items can't contain duplicates.